# About the commutatvity of a bounded self-adjoint operator with an unbounded symmetric one?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $B\in B(H)$ be self-adjoint and let $A$ be a densely defined symmetric (and closed if needed) operator such that $A^2$ is densely defined. If $BA^2\subset A^2B$ say, is there a result which gives $BA\subset AB$?

Notice that I already have a counterexample when $A^2$ is not densely defined.

Cheers,

Hichem

Comment: I don't know what kind of result you are looking for, but without further conditions, this can already fail for bounded operators ($2\times 2$ matrices even).

Comment: you may add a positive $A$ to avoid trivialities.